# Software (or website) to visualize binary sequences

Tags: digital-logic

I am looking to visualize a binary sequence for a tutorial.

For example, I have an oscillating CLK signal. Also there is serial data being inputted on INPUT pin. I want a graphical visualization of this timeinline, exactly like you would see on a logic analyzer.

i.e. to take an image from a previous post of mine:
[image]

It doesnt need to be as fancy showing ACK or anything like that. There must be a solution other than writing VHDL code and simulating or actually creating the circuit and capturing the output.

Comment: In case you are familiar with LaTeX, the tikz package is a nice thing. But I don't think you are. Are you?

Comment: I have not used LaTeX before.. Will look into it.

Comment: If you're not familiar with it, use software designed for it! Learning LaTeX is quite hard. The nice thing would be you can generate your images within the document. But I wouldn't recommend learning LaTeX just for this ;-)

Comment: I have seen many logic analyzers that boast great analyzers for things like this.

Comment: I usually do all my (more or less realtime) plotting with gnuplot. http://www.gnuplot.info/ And this for logic analyzer stuff http://www.lxtreme.nl/ols/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HERE](http://www.timing-diagrams.com/doku.php) is a link to a decent timing diagram generator.  It is free for now.  And is under active development.  Java based so portable.

THere is also [Timing diagrammer pro](http://www.syncad.com/timing_diagrammer_timing_diagram_editor.htm) from Syncad.  It is a paid app. but works well.

Comment: Don't accept so fast!  there is a distinct possibility that a better solution will pop up!

Comment: Hah. I'll unaccept yours if a better one comes up. I am using it now and I think it is fine...

Comment: @mike - the critical thing is fewer people answer questions with an accepted answer. As such, you're much less likely to get a second answer if you've accepted the first all ready.

Comment: +1 vote for unaccepting it for the time being. I'd like to see what everyone is using.